# Ground Truth Data for India

Tags: data, remote-sensing, machine-learning

I'm starting to get involved in a humanitarian project to understand crop-type and crop-yield in India to identify areas where they may be food shortages.

The current approach for this project is to process satellite data, to identify field boundaries and to use the [NDVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index) profile to understand what the crop type is and what stage of growth the crop is at. The researchers working on this have successfully done this for several countries prior. However, one challenge is that there is a shortage of ground truth data for India. The current ground truth data are points with a crop type attached, however the data is very inaccurate.

My question is:

- are there any ground-truth data-sources for vegetation in India (commercial is fine)
- are there any existing tools/apps that can be used to gather this data on the ground in a crowd-sourced way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because should be on OpenData SE.

Comment: This question could also be closed as *unfocused* (multiple questions) or *opinion-based* (more appropriate to [softwarerecs.se])

Comment: A good start is "Decadal Land Use and Land Cover Classifications across India," https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1336

Comment: @Hornbydd open data questions pertaining to spatial data are welcomed and encouraged here at GIS SE.